# Checking if service pack is installed using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

Is there a way to check with arcpy whether or not a specific ArcGIS for Desktop service pack is installed on the local machine?

More specifically, my script can only work with ArcGIS 10.1 with SP1 or higher versions. In case of earlier versions, I want to display a message to the user and stop the script before it crashes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
arcpy.GetInstallInfo()
```

You'll get a dictionary of keys and should be able to write some logic on that

> {'SourceDir': u'C:\Users\kevi5105\Documents\ArcGIS
>   10.3\Desktop\SetupFiles\', 'InstallDate': u'5/5/2015', 'InstallDir': u'c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\',
>   'ProductName': u'Desktop', 'BuildNumber': u'4322', 'InstallType':
>   u'N/A', 'Version': u'10.3', 'SPNumber': u'N/A', 'Installer':
>   u'kevin5', 'SPBuild': u'N/A', 'InstallTime': u'10:19:54'}

So, logic might be like:

```
try:
    ver = float(arcpy.GetInstallInfo()['Version'])
except:
    ver = 10.0    
try:
    sp = float(arcpy.GetInstallInfo()['SPNumber'])
except:
    sp = 0

if ver >= 10.1 and sp > 1:
  #do something
```

(I'm guessing at the SP # at 10.1... you may have to correct it)

Comment: Treating version numbers as `float`s is generally a bad idea. Consider `10.2` vs. `10.10`. Granted ESRI doesn't seem to have minor version numbers that high, but as a general principle, it's just a bad idea. You'd be better off to do `ver = tuple(int(i) for i in arcpy.GetInstallInfo()['Version'].split('.'))`. Then you specify your check later as `ver >= (10, 1)`. This will compare as expected, even for minor version numbers as high as 10.10.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and maybe in general that is a good practice, but with the Esri versions, this will work for everything released and continue to long into the future. We actually `long` the versions in our test harness and have look up tables (so we end up with values like _1005_ or _1031_).  So whether you float, long, or tuple, they'll all work.